# DNN Page settings redirect

Tags: .net, dotnetnuke

Hello I got a question regarding the option "No redirect" within the page details of a DNN website. On default this option is not selected. Which means that each page has a redirect.

You can set it manually to not redirect. Now I encountered some problems in Safari with anchors and I found on StackOverflow that if within a page a redirect header is active then the anchors will not work. So I selected the "No redirect" and everything works perfectly in all browsers.

Now I am still interested why every page had a default redirect option. What is it for? Can anyone explain me why?

Comment: Where is this setting exactly that you're using? Do you have a screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

The redirect is mostly used for these situations.

If you want a link in your menu to a specific page at 2 different locations within the menu. One page will link to the other while the second one has all the content.

When you want a link to an external URL or document from your menu.

Redirecting and old page to a new one so the visitor will not get a 404 error when using an old link.